# Replace ? to & in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have url `http://example.com/index.php?roure=test/test`
Payment system calls `http://example.com/index.php?roure=test/test?var=val`
I need make it `http://example.com/index.php?roure=test/test&var=val` in htaccess
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index.php\?roure=test/test\?var=val [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php\?roure=test/test&var=val [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: But I didn't know val parameter. To what I need replce that?